# cd to newest directory

Tags: shell, sh, aix

Not strictly bash, but rather Bourne shell if possible.
How can I programmatically cd to the newest directory? I want to install the latest package of whatever software, which is located in the newest directory. Older directories are kept for legacy systems.

Does not work:

```
find /test/sysadmin/aixinstall/programs/tcpd/* -type d | xargs ls -td | head -n 1 | xargs cd
```

#### edit:

I have an answer but it's kind of ugly so I'm giving somebody a chance to grace the internet with wisdom instead of a kluge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
cdnewest () {
    cd "$(stat -c "%Y %n" "$1"/*/ | sort -nr | head -1 | cut -d " " -f 2-)"
}

cdnewest /test/sysadmin/aixinstall/programs/tcpd
```

I'm assuming that you're looking for the newest *immediate* subdirectory, not somewhere down in the hierarchy.

Comment: I do have the GNU stat (not a builtin on AIX or kornshell), but it returns a filename. I'm having a bit of trouble getting this trimmed down to just a directory!

Comment: I think I got it now: `cd "$( find "$1"/* -prune -type d 2>/dev/null | xargs stat -c "%Y %n" 2>/dev/null | sort -nr | head -n 1 | cut -d " " -f 2-)"`

Comment: The trailing slash on my glob pattern limits the results to directories: demo: cd to a directory with both files and subdirectories and `echo *` versus `echo */`